# VB.NET Single does not equal C float

Tags: c++, vb.net, casting

I am trying to port an old C program to VB.NET

In the old program we have:

```
int bits;
float value; 

bits = -1036020416 
value = *(float *)&bits;
```

A value for bits is read in from a file and its value is -1036020416 (or 0xC23F9540 in hex)

the result is value = -47.895752

( here is the copy / paste from the locals window)

bits    0xc23f9540  int

value   -47.895752  float

Now, from EVERYTHING I can find on the internet I am told that float in VB.NET is a single. So with the following VB.NET code:

```
Dim bits as integer
Dim Value as single

bits = -1036020416
Value = Csng(bits)
```

I get the following results:

value   -1.03602042E+9  Single

Why is this happening? What am I missing?

Comment: Because *(float *)&bits; is not -1036020416

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`BitConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) class twice:

- First, convert `-1036020416` to a sequence of bytes
- Second, convert the resultant sequence to `Single` (also known as `float`)

This produces the value `-47.89575` ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VeeoJg)):

```
Dim bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(-1036020416)
Dim res = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0)
Console.WriteLine(res)
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much!!!
I was actually using bitconverter.ToInt32 when I was reading in from the file. I was able to just directly read it with the bitconverter.ToSingle